# Can we foliate the anti-de sitter space in 3 dimensions by Riemann surfaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, foliations

Can we foliate the anti-de sitter spacetime in 3 dimensions by hyperbolic Riemann surfaces? -- I think this is possible, but got stuck at finding the particular projective mapping that does this. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Not sure this is what you want, but if the anti-de Sitter spacetime in $3$ dimensions is the set $X$ of vectors of length $1$ in $\mathbf R^{2,2}$, then you have a well defined map $X\to S^1$ (take the first two coordinates and normalize) whose fiber over any vector is a two sheeted hyperboloïd.

Comment: (sorry, a sheet of a two-sheeted hyperboloïd).